# Bluetooth not working on Debian 10

Tags: debian, bluetooth, acer-aspire

I've been using Debian 10 on Acer aspire 4750, but while my Wi-Fi works fine, I have no detected Bluetooth! I have no Windows on my laptop, so I can't use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543821/bluetooth-not-working-properly-not-detecting-devices) solution.

Another point I should add is that I have a cordless mouse that works fine!